# bubble in Collection View does not grow to the appropriate height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibubbletableview

I'm building a `Chatting View Controller`. My chat bubble's constraints are as follows:

```
bubbleViewRightAnchor = bubbleView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.rightAnchor, constant: -8)
bubbleView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor).active = true
bubbleWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(200)
bubbleWidthAnchor?.active = true
bubbleViewRightAnchor?.active = true
bubbleView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.heightAnchor).active = true
```

Inside the `bubbleView` is a `textView` which is constrained inside the `bubbleView` as follows:

```
textView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bubbleView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).active = true
textView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor).active = true
textView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bubbleView.rightAnchor).active = true
textView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.heightAnchor).active = true
```

All the constraints work fine, as you can see the height anchor of the chat bubble is constrained to "self's height anchor", self being the `collection View cell`. Therefore, whatever height the cell has, the bubble will have as well. Inside the bubble is a `textView` containing all the text that was sent by the user. In another `View Controller`,  the following code which modifies the height and width of the `collection view cell` based on how much text are in the `textview` are as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var height: CGFloat = 80

    if let text = messages[indexPath.item].text {
        height = estimateFrameForText(text).height + 20
    }
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

private func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)], context: nil)
}
```

The function `estimateframefortext` estimates the frame of the cell based on the text (somehow, no idea how it does it). It works fine for messages under 600 characters or so, however, if you write more characters it adds an extra 20-30 of height to the cell, the `bubbleView` being constrained to the cell will also adopt the height, where you can now see clear space under the text. I was wondering if there were more precise functions to estimate what the height of a cell should be based on how much text there is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `UITextView` then, you could use this method:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 500))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view

let text = "The function estimateframefortext estimates the frame of the cell based on the text (somehow, no idea how it does it). It works fine for messages under 600 characters or so, however, if you write more characters it adds an extra 20-30 of height to the cell, the bubbleView being constrained to the cell will also adopt the height, where you can now see clear space under the text. I was wondering if there were more precise functions to estimate what the height of a cell should be. \n!!!!!The function estimateframefortext estimates the frame oheightTextThe function estimateframefortext estimates the frame of the cell based on the text (somehow, no idea how it does it). It works fine for messages under 600 characters or so, however, if you write more characters it adds an extra 20-30 of height to the cell, the bubbleView being constrained to the cell will also adopt the height, where you can now see clear space under the text. I was wondering if there were more precise functions to estimate what the height of a cell should be "

let label = UITextView()
view.addSubview(label)
label.text = text

let size = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 0))
let heightText = size.height
debugPrint(label.contentSize)
label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: heightText)
label.layer.borderWidth = 1
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```

or:

```
let label = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 0))
view.addSubview(label)
label.text = text
debugPrint(label.contentSize)
label.frame.size = label.contentSize
label.layer.borderWidth = 1
label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```

Explain:

`UITextView` implements the behavior for a scrollable, when you puts content[in this case, text], the textView conforms to protocol `UIScrollView`, for that, you can use contentSize that return the size of the content view.